# RMI class loading from codebase without deprecated SecurityManager?

Tags: java, classloader, rmi, java-security-manager

I'm using RMI to invoke a method that is specified to return an object of class `ClassX`.

```
ClassX xObj = remoteObject.meth(...);
```

If the remote method actually returns an instance of a locally unknown subclass `SubclassOfX` of `ClassX`, this class `SubclassOfX` is automatically downloaded from a `codebase` (as specified by the annotation on the serialized instance of `SubclassOfX`).
(for those who need it: [codebase concept in RMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465314/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-the-codebase-in-java-rmi))

Before Java17, a SecurityManager (and a policy file) had to be used to allow class loading from the codebase. But starting with Java17, the **SecurityManager is deprecated and marked for removal**.

**My question now: how to allow/control class loading from a codebase in the future?**

**Edit1**: And just to answer to comment citing jep411: I know about this document, but there is no solution/alternative given in it for this RMI use case of SecurityManager.

Comment: (Hi & Welcome!;)"There is no replacement for the Security Manager. See [JEP 411](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411) for discussion and alternatives."

Comment: ...so: "don't worry until" 27/29, as i understand: (jep411+) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: I know about jep411, but I can't find any solution/alternative given in it for this classical RMI use case of SecurityManager.

Comment: @Progman The codebase is a well-known feature of RMI. It would be familiar to anybody competent to answer the question.